# Why can't I apply CSS?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Why can't I apply CSS to an element? I cannot do this either with the developer tools (Browser Toolbox) or by writing the desired settings in `userChrome.css`, yes in about:config the setting is activated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tor Browser *is* a Firefox, but it's explicitly tuned for privacy, so - just like in your case - many ubiquitous features are discarded and filtered for the sake of fingerprinting prevention